# Is there any good way to get microphone audio input to server using just a web browser?

Tags: browser, audio, cross-browser

I need to get audio input from users having just browsers (and not only IE). Is there any good way to get audio stream with a brouser to server. 
If it possible to avoid Java, flash etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with flash.

Have a look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000297.html

P.S.: Html alone can't do it. You would need a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need a plugin of some sort. HTML itself doesn't support microphone input.

-- EDIT
As answered a few secs before me, you can use many third party plugins, such as flash and java. But you cannot avoid not using them.